# How do I change the default character encoding in IIS on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, encoding, charset

When validating my web page using the W3C Validator, I noticed that although I specify ISO-8859-1 encoding in my HTML, the web server seems to be specifying UTF-8 encoding in the HTTP headers.

I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find a way to change this - am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured this out now, and perhaps the reason for the lack of answers was that my question omitted a crucial detail, which was that this is an ASP.NET web site.

The content encoding is set in the `Machine.config` file when the .NET Framework is installed, and it defaults to UTF-8. You can edit this file which will affect the response encoding of all ASP.NET sites, or you can override it on a per-site basis using the `<globalisation>` element in each site's `Web.config` file.

[Globalization Element Reference (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you could try  tags in the header of your html file. You could also try to check your HTML files for the UTF8-BOM. If a hex editor shows three characters before the first regular character, that would be the reason why IIS might send out Content-Type-headers with that encoding.

Comment: As I said, I already specify ISO-8859-1 encoding in my HTML (with meta tags) - the W3C Validator tells me that there is a conflict between this and the server headers. And the files are all saved with ISO-8859-1 encoding.